# cloning tr of a table without cloning the values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tr

I have simple jquery external java script which which clones the last row of table and increments the ids of fields in the row by 1. I now have the problem upon cloning if there is data within the row before i clone the values are copied as well. I am trying for the value attributes of input fields in the clone row to be empty when cloned.

jquery javascript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn_AddTruck").click(function () {
               var $tableBody = $('#tbl_invTruck').find("tbody"),
                $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),
                $trNew = $trLast.clone();
                // Find by attribute 'id'
                $trNew.find('[id]').each(function () {
                    var num = this.id.replace(/\D/g, '');
                    if (!num) {
                        num = 0;
                    }
                    // Remove numbers by first regexp
                    this.id = this.id.replace(/\d/g, '') 
                        // increment number
                        + (1 + parseInt(num, 10));
                });

                $trLast.after($trNew); 


            });

        });
```

Comment: Java and nothing to do with this....

Comment: You could build a hidden tr with no values which is just for cloning.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to keep all the `td` child element of the clone, but only clear their content:

```
$trNew.find('td').html('');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btn_AddTruck").click(function () {
    let $tableBody = $('#tbl_invTruck').find("tbody");
    let $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
    let $trNew = $trLast.clone();
    
    $trNew.find('td').html('')
    
    $trLast.after($trNew); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn_AddTruck">Click me<button>

<table id="tbl_invTruck">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you don't care about any of the child element, you could just clear the innerHTML of the `tr` element:

```
$trNew.html('');
```

Comment: i also tried this method as well which is cloning the table row but without any data at all. I am really looking to clone the row and have the value attribute of the input field blank

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn_AddTruck").click(function () {
           var $tableBody = $('#tbl_invTruck').find("tbody"),
            $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),
            $trNew = $trLast.clone();
            // Find by attribute 'id'
            $trNew.find('[id]').each(function () {
                var num = this.id.replace(/\D/g, '');
                if (!num) {
                    num = 0;
                }
                // Remove numbers by first regexp
                this.id = this.id.replace(/\d/g, '') 
                    // increment number
                    + (1 + parseInt(num, 10));
            });
            //empty the td content
            $trNew.find("td").html(""); 
            $trLast.after($trNew); 
        });

    });
```